# Testing Multiple http links within a text.file

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Hi I need to test several http links that are saved in a txt file. The logic is as follows: read text file, parse html, read each line beginning with http:// separately, and test each one async. Here is the code I have used so far, but nothing happens.

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\Conal_Curran\\OneDrive\\C#\\MyProjects\\Web Crawler\\URLTester\\OP.htm");

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"href=\""(.*?)\""");
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>();

            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                string url = m.Groups["url"].Value;
                Uri testUri = null;
                if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out testUri))
                {
                    uris.Add(testUri);


                    var lines = File.ReadLines(url);
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        if (text.StartsWith("http://"))
                        {

                            var request = WebRequest.Create(text);
                            var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory
                            .FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
                            request.EndGetResponse,
                            null);
                            Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);

                            if (response == null)
                            {
                                BrokenLinks.Text = text;
                                label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                BrokenLinks.Text = "All URLS Are OK";
                                label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No URLS Selected");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as using a regex to pick out the http links I tried using the htmlagilitypack:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = hw.Load("C:\\Users\\Conal_Curran\\OneDrive\\C#\\MyProjects\\Web Crawler\\URLTester\\OP.htm");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("url"))
        {
            // Get the value of the HREF attribute
            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", "Saved!");
```

However I keep getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". This occurs at

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {

Comment: For the HtmlAgilityPack, try this one              var html = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Conal_Curran\\OneDrive\\C#\\MyProjects\\Web Crawler\\URLTester\\OP.htm");
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);  and doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a") instead

Answer (score 0):

Your regex:

```
Regex.Matches(text, @"href=\""(.*?)\""");
```

Clearly it doesn't have any named groups defined.

You select the group "url" in your code which is not found:

```
string url = m.Groups["url"].Value;
```

Try this regex:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("", @"href=\""(?<url>[^\""]+)\""");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that but for some reason when I click the that button it doesn't seem to run. Does the collection of links in "string text" need to be stored within an array in order to send webrequests to each link?

Comment: Could you put a break-point somewhere in the method and find where it stopped or exception happened?